# Bind value from input to properties of an object

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I have a question on how to bind input value to a an object?
TypeScript-file:

```
private shareholder = { 
shares : 'value from input'
name:  'value from input'
}
```

and the html looks like

```
<input name="shares" ng-model="shares"  type="number" required>
<input name="name" ng-model="name" required>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `shareholder`is an object on your 'myController', do this:

```
<div ng-controller="myController as $ctrl">

    <input name="shares" ng-model="$ctrl.shareholder.shares"  type="number" required />
    <input name="name" ng-model="$ctrl.shareholder.name" required />

</div>
```

Also, because you access the data outside your controller, make your `shareholder` object `public`.

---

If you're using the plain old `$scope`, then you can do the following:

```
$scope.shareholder = { 
    shares: 'value from input'
    name: 'value from input'
}
```

view:

```
<input name="shares" ng-model="shareholder.shares"  type="number" required />
<input name="name" ng-model="shareholder.name" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

**Controller**

```
var shareholder = { 
shares : 'value from input'
name:  'value from input'
}
```

**Html**

```
<input name="shares" ng-model="shareholder.shares"  type="number" required>
<input name="name" ng-model="shareholder.name" required>
```